# NebulaGraph Studio: failed to open connection after upgraded to v3.1.0

Tags: nebula-graph

NebulaGraph Studio Version: 3.3.0
NebulaGraph Database Version: 3.1.0

Failed to open connection, error: `incompatible version between client and server: Graph client version(2.6.0) is not accepted, current graph client white list: 3.0.03.1.0…`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your NebulaGraph Studio version is not compatible with the NebulaGraph database version.

Upgrade your NebulaGraph Studio to solve this issue. For the valid version, see [NebulaGraph Studio docs](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/nebula-studio/about-studio/st-ug-what-is-graph-studio/#version_compatibility).